# Google Sheets Arithmetic Search

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have two Google sheets tabs:

I.)

```
      --A--  --B--
--1-- type   lessThan10Apart
--2-- Car    1
--3-- Plane  0
```

II.)

```
      --A--   --B--    --C--
--1-- type    sourceA  sourceB
--2-- Car     1        100
--3-- Plane   10       100
--4-- Car     2        4
```

My question is how to create the **lessThan10Apart** formula above. lessThan10Apart should match up the type from sheet I to sheet II and only count the rows that: Are less than 10 units between A and B. But you can also imagine wanting to do any kind of arithmetic between columns B and C and running a COUNT.

My first attempt is something along the lines of:

```
=COUNTIFS('sheetII'!A:A),$A2,  //Match column A
ABS('sheetII'!C:C-'sheetII'!B:B)<10 //Doesn't work!
)
```

The problem is that you can't seem to be able to do range calculations like this in COUNTIFS.

Comment: Why is Car a 2? Seems to me that there is only one row with difference less than 10.

Comment: Sorry. I had a more complicated example before and stripped stuff out but forgot to update! Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the count (per F4 in supplied image),

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS(B2:B4-C2:C4)<10))
```

For the validSum (sum of absolute difference between B & C; per G4 in supplied image),

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS(B2:B4-C2:C4)<10), ABS(B2:B4-C2:C4))
```

Do not use full column references. Minimize your referenced ranges.

[image]

<sup>Discard the **Car** text in E4 in the above image.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! What is the -- in the SUMPRODUCT above? I haven't come across this.

Comment: Google *double unary*.